# Can't reach my cloud VM from web (Oracle Compute Instance )

Tags: nginx, virtual-machine, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a VM in Oracle cloud, to which I'm able to ssh. 
It runs an Angular app on localhost:4200, and in order to browse there, I installed Nginx, but I feel like it's not the issue. 
When browsing to the public IP provided by oracle, i just get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
Pinging to the server does not work - request timeout (as far as i know, it's fine on cloud VMs). 
What can I do to get access to my Angular App?

Here are the ingress rules in the subnet:
[image: Subnet ingress rules]

Here's my nginx `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Here are the ports open in the `firewalld`:

`80/tcp 443/tcp 4200/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to open all the ports on oracle subnet level.
This is done by adding an ingress rule that allows all connections from all IPs on all ports
0.0.0.0/0
and not specifying any port.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).